# R shiny ggplot geomline

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

[image: Out put of code in R]

I tried to generate a line chart with 3 lines by years but i can only generate 1 line with my code, what should I do

Comment: box(
    title = " Records in Hours by Year"
    ,status = "primary"
    ,solidHeader = TRUE 
    ,collapsible = TRUE 
    ,plotOutput("totalpaidmonth", height = "400px")
  ) 
)



  
  library(timeDate)
  
  crimessum2<-crimes %>%
    group_by(YEAR,HOUR) %>%
    summarise(Numbers = sum(Numbers))
  
  
  output$totalpaidmonth <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = crimessum2)+ 
      geom_line(mapping = aes(x=HOUR, y = Numbers,col = YEAR))+
      xlab("HOUR")+
      ylab("Total Paid by Insurance in $$")+
      ggtitle(" ")
  })
  
  
}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a look at [reprex] for pointers to writting a question which is likely to get a good response. You are on the right lines: Please include a minimal representation of your data - use `dput(your_data)` or `dput(head(your_data, n = 20))` if your data set is large; the code you have tried and the expected output.

Comment: My data is the Boston Crime report with the filter code=301 , YEAR(2016,2017,182018)

Comment: try including `group = YEAR` in your `geom_line` `aes` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Without seeing your data it is guess work on my part.

I suspect YEAR is being treated as a continuous variable and to get distinct colours you need YEAR to be a discrete variable.

```
ggplot(data = crimessum2)+ 
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x=HOUR, y = Numbers, col = factor(YEAR), group = YEAR))+ 
  xlab("HOUR")+ 
  ylab("Total Paid by Insurance in $$")+ 
  ggtitle(" ")
```